# not getting data if i choose same date for from and to

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i am doing date range using mongoose aggregation when i choose two different dates am getting data but when choose same date am not getting data on perticular date,for example if i choose 23 and 24 dates am getting data but when i choose 23 & 23 am not getting data ,please help me to fix the issue

````
        if(from && to ) {

                let fromdate = moment(from).format();
                let todate = moment(to).format()
                console.log(new Date(fromdate),new Date(todate),'dfdfd')
                console.log(fromdate,todate,'dfdfd')
                return await Message.aggregate([
                    {
                        $match: {unanswered: true}
                    },


                    {
                        $match: {
                            createdAt: {
                                $gte: new Date(fromdate),
                                $lte: new Date(todate)

                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $group: {
                            _id: {$toLower: '$message'},
                            id: {$first: '$_id'},
                            display: {$first: '$message'},
                            createdAt: {$first: '$createdAt'},
                            totalQuantity: {$sum: 1}
                        }
                    }
                ]).sort({totalQuantity: 'desc'});

        }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't use `$gte` function for greater than or equal ?

```
[{
        $match: {
            "unanswered": true
        }
    },


    {
        $match: {
            "createdAt": {
                $gte: new Date(fromdate),
                $lte: new Date(todate)

            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                $toLower: '$message'
            },
            id: {
                $first: '$_id'
            },
            display: {
                $first: '$message'
            },
            createdAt: {
                $first: '$createdAt'
            },
            totalQuantity: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: yes i edited my code am using $gte which is greater than or equal and $lte lessdhan or equal

Comment: but not getting data

Comment: Try with query above, I've changed field names to string.